# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{\overline{0}\}$ is not a group if $p$ is not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

The answer is too short that I think I've gone wrong at some point!

Q: If $p$ is prime, then the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ form a group of order $p-1$ under multiplication. Show that this statement is false if $p$ is not prime.

A: $p$ is not prime, so take it $p=4$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_4 \backslash \{\bar{0}\}=\{\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}\}$. It is a monoid, but since $\bar{2}$ does not have an inverse element, then $\mathbb{Z}_4 \backslash \{\bar{0}\}$ is not a group.

Comment: You need to show that's true for every non prime not just for 4

Comment: @AndréNicolas Edit made.

Comment: Essentially the proof is a one-liner : $\text{gcd}(n, k)$ is $1$ for all  $0 < k < n$ iff $n$ is prime.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Any ideas for that?

Comment: To elaborate on @Mathmo123's comment: You merely show "There exist nonprime $p$ such that $\mathbb Z_p$ is not a group" while the problem statement is about "For all nonprime $p$, $\mathbb Z_p$ is not a group".

Comment: Is this right? :
Want to show: $\forall p\notin \mathbb{P}; \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not group. On contrary, $\exists p\notin \mathbb{P}; \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a group. Take $\mathbb{Z}_4$ which is not a group and that contradicts the previous statement, proving the first statement.

Comment: *Please* don't spread this terminology of writing "$\mathbb{Z}_p$" for the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of integers mod $p$.  The notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is standard for the ring of $p$-adic integers, and using it for anything else is horribly confusing.  If "$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$" is really too long to write, one can write "$\mathbb{Z}/(p)$" instead, or even just "$\mathbb{Z}/p$", but *not* "$\mathbb{Z}_p$".

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Many elementary number theory textbooks use $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ to denote $\,\Bbb Z/n.\ $ There is little that the OP can do about such overloaded notaition.

Comment: Agree with Bill. Whenever the context makes the meaning clear $\Bbb{Z}_n$ may mean the ring $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. When $p$-adic interpretation is a live possibility, the latter (kludgier) notation is (IMO should be) used to denote the ring of residue classes of integers.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Yes, that's what I'm complaining about.  Elementary textbooks should be particularly careful to avoid confusing notations, so that their unsuspecting readers don't come across $\mathbb{Z}_p$ thinking "oh I know about this" and become completely confused.  OP should at least be told that this notation is bad: I didn't intend my comment as blame, but as a warning.  (I do blame the authors of such textbooks, though.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen , perhaps the notation $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$ for the p-adic integers is the bad one? If many textbooks use this notation for integers modulo p then perhaps the more advanced material's notation is the one that should be changed.

Comment: @Timbuc: Unless you're suggesting to change the notation for quotients in general, the right notation for the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $p\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and I know no other notation for $p$-adics that would be widely understood.  But more importantly, I don't see what is pedagogically gained by using an overloaded notation when "$\mathbb{Z}/p$" is a single stroke more than "$\mathbb{Z}_p$" (and exactly as long in TeX) and unambigous — when this obscures a general mathematical construct (quotients).  How, exactly, does this benefit beginners?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Haha, very fun point (+1). I think it's fine to use it as only the ones working with number theory knows the difference between $\Bbb Z_p$ and $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Sometimes it's even in standard books (e.g., Dummit & Foote) so it can't be entirely refuted either. What is _really_ annoying is that some geometers sometimes use $\Bbb Z_p$ to denote cyclic groups and when they need to work with $p$-adics, they just write $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** if $n$ is composite, then the set of non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n>1$ be a non-prime natural number. Therefore there exist $a,b \in \{2, 3 ,\ldots n-1\}$ such that $p = ab$ and consequently $0 = ab$ in ${\mathbb Z}_n$. Then one can see that $a,b$ do not have inverse, since otherwise, if $a'$ and $b'$ be their inverse, one have that $a.a'=b.b'=1$ from one hand, and from other hand $ab=0$, where these together means that $a=b=0$ which contradicts $a,b \in \{2, 3 ,\ldots n-1\}$. So ${\mathbb Z}_n$ can not be a multiplicative group.

Comment: Didn't you finish your answer in the second line? Basically, you showed that if $\;p\;$ is not prime then there are $\;a,b\in\Bbb Z_p\setminus\{0\}\;$  such that $\;ab\notin\Bbb Z_p\setminus\{0\}\;$ .

Comment: Yes! It was just for more explanation!